# What that this line means in a make file `DOCKER := $(shell command -v docker)`

Tags: shell, makefile

`$(shell command -v docker)` What `command` means? it's being used in a Makefile.

I saw this in a github repository that I'm trying to understand.

It looks like it's setting a variable with a command to test if docker is installed, and stop the build if its not, the problem is this that I don't have a command installed and I tryed to install command in ubuntu but it can't find it, looking on internet how to install this commad command seems realy difficult because of its name, `how to install command in linux/ubuntu` didn't bring anything useful, also search for this being using on Makefiles trying to get some clue but nothing so far.

Running the build command seems to work becuse it build the image and yes I have docker installed, but still getting that message in the terminal `make: command: Command not found`

Any idea?

make build output (trucated):

```
$ make build                                                                                                                                                                                   
make: command: Command not found                                                                                                                                                               
make: command: Command not found                                                                                                                                                               
docker build -t codelytv/typescript-ddd-skeleton:dev .                                                                                                                                         
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.023MB 
.....
```

This is the Makefile:

```
.PHONY = default deps build test start clean start-database

IMAGE_NAME := codelytv/typescript-ddd-skeleton
SERVICE_NAME := app

# Test if the dependencies we need to run this Makefile are installed
DOCKER := $(shell command -v docker)
DOCKER_COMPOSE := $(shell command -v docker-compose)
deps:
ifndef DOCKER
    @echo "Docker is not available. Please install docker"
    @exit 1
endif
ifndef DOCKER_COMPOSE
    @echo "docker-compose is not available. Please install docker-compose"
    @exit 1
endif

default: build

# Build image
build:
    docker build -t $(IMAGE_NAME):dev .

# Run tests
test: build
    docker-compose run --rm $(SERVICE_NAME) bash -c 'npm run build && npm run test'

# Start the application
start: build
    docker-compose up $(SERVICE_NAME) && docker-compose down

# Clean containers
clean:
    docker-compose down --rmi local --volumes --remove-orphans

# Start mongodb container in background
start_database:
    docker-compose up -d mongo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means is that the person who wrote this makefile wasn't careful enough to write it in a portable way.

The `command` command is part of the shell (which is why you won't see it if you look for it in the GNU make manual).  Not only that, it's part of the bash shell specifically: it is not a POSIX sh standard command.  The bash man page says:

```
   command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
          Run  command  with  args  suppressing  the normal shell function
          lookup.  Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH are
          executed.
```

Basically, running `command docker ...` means that any shell alias or function named `docker` is ignored, and only the actual `docker` command is run.

However, GNU make always runs `/bin/sh` as its shell, including for both recipes and for the `$(shell ...)` function.

So, if you're on a system (such as Red Hat or CentOS or Fedora GNU/Linux) where the `/bin/sh` is a link to the bash shell, then the above command will work.

However, if you're on a system (such as Debian or Ubuntu GNU/Linux) where the `/bin/sh` is a link to a simpler POSIX shell such as dash, then the above command will not work.

In reality, this is not needed because there won't be any shell aliases or functions defined in the shell that make invokes, regardless.  However, if the author wants to use bash shell features in their makefiles and allow them to work, they also need to tell make to use bash as its shell, by adding this to their makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

(of course this assumes that the user has a `/bin/bash` on their system, but...)